# Why is all() slower than many "and" commands? Python

Tags: python, tags, command

Can someone please explain the reason for why the first code runs faster than the second one?

```
# First example
if a%1 == 0 and a%2 == 0 and a%3 == 0 and a%4 == 0 and a%5 == 0:
    # do something if True

# Second example
list1 = list(range(1,6,1))
if all(a%i == 0 for i in list1)
    # do something if True
```

*The a variable is changing if false

I know that the 1 and 4 can be excluded but it is for a school paper in which I'm going to just use it to show a bad example. Still, I want to know the reason.
Thanks

Comment: How did you compare the execution times?

Comment: Used the time module. The original code is counting up to 20 and then the difference is very distinct.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example you create a list dynamically, so it will take extra time, for you will execute all the comparisons anyway, but adding the memory reservation overhead (you are dealing with memory, which is some magnitude orders slower than dealing with processor registers).

Comment: Sorry didn't get any of that. Any simplified answer?

Comment: @SimonÖnnered, essentially its not a fair comparison since the second example includes creating the list ```a%i == 0```

Comment: When creating a list, you need to do a memory reservation for its contents (Python does that for you). To this end, the processor will ask the main memory where it has enough space together for allocating the list, and after that it will do the comparisons of your if clause. This memory acess is really slow compared to processor speed.
Since the processor will have the instructions (comparisons) on cache (fast access memory), acessing them takes little time. Loading a list on main memory could take 100 times longer, maybe.

Comment: @wnnmawWhat do you mean? Creating a list up to 10000 takes barely a milisecond. How could that be the reason for being way more timeconsuming. The difference is about 1 sec.

Comment: Hmm... If the difference is so big, it could have something to do with how Python deals with your "all()" call. I guess it is creating a function wich maps different values into "a". I don't know how Python does that, but it should be it.
Anyway, the point is that in the first way you just do comparisons, while in the second one, you do the same comparisons plus other calculations that suppose a time overhead.

Comment: @user3407000 So what you're saying is that the list is being uploaded from an part of the memory which is taking a bit longer to access, than to simply test each condition in the first example?

Another question then, since the second one is more general, I mean you can change one or two things and it can work for eg. 1 to 100. With the first you'll have to write a condition for each up to 100. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Creating and accessing the list does take some time, but the main offender should be the for loop. Which as inherently slow in python. Putting the creation of the list, and changing both to access the elements of that list, still show this time difference.

Comment: @SimonÖnnered, I just ran a test myself and after _10,000 trials_ example 1 took 0.024 seconds and example 2 took 0.055 seconds, which is negligibly different

Comment: But with large numbers (liske 1,4 million) it makes a big difference, right?

Comment: @SimonÖnnered, sure, the difference increases with more trials, but the difference is only 0.38 seconds.  Interestingly, if you replace creating ```list1``` and substitute ```range(1,6,1)``` in its place and make the expression a list comprehension, it becomes about twice as fast (```if all([a%i == 0 for i in range(1,6,1)]):```), 0.621 s to 0.39 s

Comment: @SimonÖnnered Yes, in current computer architectures, memory is structured on several levels according to its size and speed of access. The biggest, the slowest to access. In your computer you have a hard drive, RAM memory, several levels of caches and processor registries. The compiled program instructions should be in cache when called. You create the list on run time, so you have to do RAM memory reservation.
Regarding your second question, you have to adopt a compromise solution: you can spare some code writing in a trade-off for your program's speed. It is up to you to decide.

Comment: For a deeper explanation, you could consider checking "Modern Operative Systems", by Andrew S. Tanenbaum, starting by the chapter on the introduction that talks about Computer's hardware (Chapter 1.3 on the 3rd edition).

Comment: Very late to the party, but I came here because I had the same observation and I think my approach is worth sharing. What I ended up doing is writing the first check out, and adding the remainder using `all`, i.e. `if a%list1[0] == 0 and all(a%i == 0 for i in list1[1:])` in your example. In my case this meant the `all` was not executed often.